# Why can not work post request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, post, application-pool

There was a problem. Sometimes post requests dont work. Perhaps this is due to restart the application pool.

How this situation can be traced whether the request comes into our application or request was in the queue http.sys.

How can I track whether the request came to the site?

And the reasons why he can not send a response to a post request?

Comment: Have you enabled IIS logging, including [failed request tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)?

Comment: I add failed request tracing on my web server. And configure next settings: All content (*) and Time token (in seconds - 10).

Comment: When i configure the settings for Recycle Application Pool at a Scheduled Time in 8:00 then my site work good. And when i back default settings for Application Pool, post request stopped working again..

Comment: Request Diagnostics - STATUS_CODE 200, 48189 ms

Comment: So the next thing to do is add more diagnostics to your code: you need to work out under what circumstances posts start failing. There is nothing obvious that would cause this apart from the general "something changes in the state of the process", which is of course unhelpful.